# Solving $\int {\frac{2 \sin(x) \cos(x)}{\sin^4(x) + \cos^4(x)}}\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

[See this link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BcBq.png). I am having trouble with this one as well. Any hints or help appreciated.

$$\int{\frac{2\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\sin^4(x)+\cos^4(x)}}\,dx$$

Comment: Do you mean ?$$\int {\frac{2 \sin(x) \cos(x)}{\sin^4(x) + \cos^4(x)}}\, dx$$

Comment: Use this substitution :$$sin^2x=u\\du=2sin x cos x\\cos^2x=1-u^2$$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**

For the denominator 
$$\sin^4(x)+\cos^4(x)=(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x))^2-2\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)=1-\frac 12\sin^2(2x)=\frac 12(1+\cos^2(2x))$$

For the numerator $$2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\sin(2x)$$

So $$\int {\frac{2 \sin(x) \cos(x)}{\sin^4(x) + \cos^4(x)}}\, dx=\int \frac{2\sin(2x)}{1+\cos^2(2x)}\,dx$$
Changing variable $t=\cos(2x)$ looks quite promising.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Multiply numerator and denumerator by $\sec^4 x$

$$\dots=2\int\frac{\tan x \sec^2 x}{1+\tan^4 x}dx$$

Now, set $t:=\tan x$ so $dt=\sec^2 x dx$

$$=2\int \frac{t}{t^4+1}dt=\dots$$

Comment: Better to set $\tan^2x=t$

Comment: For every problem there always are at least 3 solutions :-)

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\int {\frac{2 \sin x \cos x}{\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x}}\,\mathrm dx&=\int {\frac{2 \sin x \cos x}{1-2\sin^2x\cos^2x}}\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\int\frac{\sin 2x}{1-\frac12\sin^22x}\mathrm dx\\
&=\int\frac{\sin 2x}{1+\cos^22x}\mathrm d(2x)\\
&=-\arctan\cos2x\;.
\end{align}

Comment: You are wrong by a constant factor.

Comment: @Yves: Ah, yes, thanks, I took the $2$ into account twice :-). Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

With an obvious shorthand notation, 
$$\int\frac{4sc}{2(s^4+c^4)}dx=\int\frac{(s^2-c^2)'}{(s^2-c^2)^2+(s^2+c^2)^2}dx=\int\frac{(s^2-c^2)'}{(s^2-c^2)^2+1}dx.$$
Hence

$$\arctan(s^2-c^2).$$